# Logistic regression alternative with non continuous predictor variables

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, binary-data

I have a data set where I have a binary dependent variable but my predictors are mostly categorical or binary, with a couple of predictors that are continuous. 
The other thing with my data set is that I have squewed results in that much more of my responses are 0 rather than 1. It is however, quite a large data set. 
The most appropriate stats I could think of was a logistic regression but then one of the assumptions of that is for continuous predictors. Do you have any suggestions for the method I could use to analyse this?

Many thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Where did you hear/read that one of the assumptions of logistic regression is that you must have continuous predictors?  This is just not the case.  Your predictors can be of any type.  Why don't you tell us more about what you are trying to do and then we might be able to help.

Comment: Hi Stats student. Thank you for your help. I must have misread my textbook.

Answer (score 1):

As @StatsStudent mentions in the comments, logistic regression does not require continuous predictors.  As best I can tell from your description, logistic regression should be fine for your situation.